# Python: How can I fix an AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, attributeerror

I have the code:

```
df_mean_woman = df_mean_woman.rename(index = {"Less than 1 year":0}, inplace = True)
df_mean_woman
```

And when I run it I get the error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-94a5cc6acf63> in <module>
----> 1 df_woman = df_woman.rename(index = {"Less than 1 year":0},
      2                                   #"More than 50 years":int(51)},
      3                                   inplace = True)
      4 df_woman

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

Although the error goes away when I simply type `df_mean_woman.rename(index = {"Less than 1 year":0}, inplace = True)`
But I cannot simply do that because I need to call df again later. I have tried doing quite a few things to fix this, but nothing seems to work. I do not think it is because "Less than 1 year" is not spelled correctly. My main issue seems to be that when I print out df_mean_woman (before the rename) it is said that df does not exist.
When I rerun Juptyr I am able to print out df but all that gets printed is 'None'.

My full code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
%matplotlib inline
df_new = df.copy()
df_new = df_new.drop(['Age1stCode','CompTotal','Respondent', 'MainBranch', 'Hobbyist', 'Age', 'CompFreq', 'Country', 'CurrencyDesc', 'CurrencySymbol', 'DatabaseDesireNextYear', 'DatabaseWorkedWith', 'DevType', 'EdLevel', 'Employment', 'Ethnicity', 'JobFactors', 'JobSat', 'JobSeek', 'LanguageDesireNextYear', 'LanguageWorkedWith', 'MiscTechDesireNextYear', 'MiscTechWorkedWith', 'NEWCollabToolsDesireNextYear', 'NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith', 'NEWDevOps', 'NEWDevOpsImpt', 'NEWEdImpt', 'NEWJobHunt', 'NEWJobHuntResearch', 'NEWLearn', 'NEWOffTopic', 'NEWOnboardGood', 'NEWOtherComms', 'NEWOvertime', 'NEWPurchaseResearch', 'NEWPurpleLink', 'NEWSOSites', 'NEWStuck', 'OpSys', 'OrgSize', 'PlatformDesireNextYear', 'PlatformWorkedWith', 'PurchaseWhat', 'Sexuality', 'SOAccount', 'SOComm', 'SOPartFreq', 'SOVisitFreq', 'SurveyEase', 'SurveyLength', 'Trans', 'UndergradMajor', 'WebframeDesireNextYear', 'WebframeWorkedWith', 'WelcomeChange', 'WorkWeekHrs', 'YearsCodePro'], axis = 'columns')
df_new = df_new.dropna()
df_new    
df_woman = df_new.drop(index=df_new[df_new['Gender'] != 'Woman'].index, inplace=True)
df_woman = df_new
df_woman = df_woman.drop(['Gender'], axis ='columns')
df_news = df_new.copy()

df_woman = df_woman.rename(index = {"Less than 1 year":int(0)},
                                  #"More than 50 years":int(51)},
                                  inplace = True)
df_woman['YearsCode'] = df_woman['YearsCode'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>2}'.format(x))
df_mean_woman = df_woman.groupby('YearsCode')['ConvertedComp'].mean().sort_index()

df_mean_woman
```

Comment: df.drop returns none if you use inplace as True, so here df_woman will be `None` type, so it wont have an attribute `rename`

Comment: from the docs about the return value of drop: `DataFrame without the removed index or column labels or None if inplace=True.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are excluding more columns then you are including, so it would be easier to make a list of the columns you want rather than a much longer list of the columns you want to drop.

Overall, I would not use `drop` and would instead use `loc` for most of these operations. It is also unclear why you are trying to manipulate the index rather than the column values.

```
# looks like stackoverflow survey data
df = pd.read_csv('survey_results_public.csv')

unwanted = {'Age1stCode','CompTotal','Respondent', 'MainBranch', 'Hobbyist', 'Age', 'CompFreq', 'Country', 
            'CurrencyDesc', 'CurrencySymbol', 'DatabaseDesireNextYear', 'DatabaseWorkedWith', 'DevType', 
            'EdLevel', 'Employment', 'Ethnicity', 'JobFactors', 'JobSat', 'JobSeek', 'LanguageDesireNextYear', 
            'LanguageWorkedWith', 'MiscTechDesireNextYear', 'MiscTechWorkedWith', 'NEWCollabToolsDesireNextYear', 
            'NEWCollabToolsWorkedWith', 'NEWDevOps', 'NEWDevOpsImpt', 'NEWEdImpt', 'NEWJobHunt', 'NEWJobHuntResearch', 
            'NEWLearn', 'NEWOffTopic', 'NEWOnboardGood', 'NEWOtherComms', 'NEWOvertime', 'NEWPurchaseResearch', 
            'NEWPurpleLink', 'NEWSOSites', 'NEWStuck', 'OpSys', 'OrgSize', 'PlatformDesireNextYear', 
            'PlatformWorkedWith', 'PurchaseWhat', 'Sexuality', 'SOAccount', 'SOComm', 'SOPartFreq', 'SOVisitFreq', 
            'SurveyEase', 'SurveyLength', 'Trans', 'UndergradMajor', 'WebframeDesireNextYear', 'WebframeWorkedWith', 
            'WelcomeChange', 'WorkWeekHrs', 'YearsCodePro'}

# no need to copy dataframe before selecting columns
df_new = df.loc[:, list(set(df.columns) - unwanted)]

# use .loc to make df_woman
df_woman = df_new.loc[df_new['Gender'] != 'Woman', df_new.columns.drop('Gender')]

# convert strings to numeric values
df_woman['YearsCode'] = df_woman['YearsCode'].str.replace('Less than 1 year', '0')
df_woman['YearsCode'] = df_woman['YearsCode'].str.replace('More than 50 years', '51')
df_woman['YearsCode'] = pd.to_numeric(df_woman['YearsCode'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)

# now groupby and analyze
df_woman.groupby('YearsCode')['ConvertedComp'].mean()
```

Comment: Also, I just realised that the copies of the list were made when I was still playing around with the code, and I just forgot to delete it

Comment: Oh, and also, you do not need to have the `.str`

Answer (score 0):

```
df_woman = df_new.drop(index=df_new[df_new['Gender'] != 'Woman'].index, inplace=True)
```

`.drop()` returns `None` when `inplace=True`.

See here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html